# Bind click function for every row of table in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, binding

I have a table with multiple rows which shows name and model of different items, It has "add" button in last column of every row, i want to get the name of that item (which is 2nd column of every row) when i click add button, but it only works for the first row, how can I make it work for every row of the table

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn-add").on("click",function() {
        var $row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Find the row
        var $text = $row.find(".this-name").text(); // Find the text

        // Let's test it out
        alert($text);
    });
});
```

my table is repeated in a loop, HTML is as follows:

```
<tr>
    <td class="this-id" style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $id;?></td>
    <td class="this-name" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 15px;"><?php echo $name;?></td>
    <td style="text-align: left; padding-left: 15px;"><?php echo $level;?></td>
    <td style="text-align: left; padding-left: 15px;"><?php echo $number;?></td>
    <td style="text-align: left; padding-left: 15px;"><button id="btn-add">Add Item</button></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: the same `id` should only occur once in a document, use `class` instead.

Comment: Add a common class and use class selector to bind evnt handler

Comment: u mean instead of `#btn-add` i should use `.btn-add` ?? @Satpal

Comment: @SyedHarisAliGhaznavi, Yes, `<button class="btn-add">` and `$(".btn-add")`

Comment: @Satpal Thanks it worked :)

Comment: Id shiuld be unique and used only once. Or the selector will return the first matched element. Use class or generate unique ids like id ="btn-add-" + number